# adding two dictionaries of ints

Tags: python, python-3.x

I think I have the right idea of solving this function, but it's not getting the desired result shown in the docstring i test it. Can anyone please help me fix this?

```
def add_dicts(d1, d2):
'''(dict, dict) -> dict
Parameters d1 and d2 are dicts where each key is an int and each value is an 
int. Return dict d1 with the contents of d2 added to d1. More concisely, if 
key k is in d1 and in d2, update d1[k] to be the sum of d1[k] and d2[k]. If 
d2 has a key that is not in d1, add the key value pair from d2 to d1.
>>> d1 = {1:1, 2:1, 3:2}
>>> d2 = {1:3, 3:1, 4:1}
>>> d = add_dicts(d1, d2)
>>> d == {1:4, 2:1, 3:3, 4:1}
True
'''
for (key, value) in d1.items():
    if key in d1 and key in d2:
        d1[key] = d1[key] + d2[key]
        if key in d2 and key not in d1:
            d1[key] = {key: value}
return d1
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of iterating over `d1`'s items, iterate over `d2`:

```
for a, b in d2.items():
   if a in d1:
      d1[a] += b
   else:
      d1[a] = b
```

Comment: Why iterate over d2?

Comment: @bigez since `d1` is the dictionary to be updated, it is best to iterate over `d2` because it is a cleaner and inline with the problem statement, which specifically mentions a `d2` to `d1` update sequence.

Comment: so what is the += b? just keep adding the value to the key if the key is in d1?

Comment: @bigez `+= b`  is the desired update of `d1[a]` if `d1` contains key `a`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `dict.get` function to use a default value of `0` when the key is not found in `d1`:

```
for key, val in d2.items():
    d1[key] = d1.get(key, 0) + val
```

Comment: Why is there a 0?

Comment: @bigez if d1 doesn't contain an entry for key, it uses 0 as the default value to return